# make content inside divs display in the same locations

Tags: css

i have a page that displays products on my website inside boxes (https://s21.postimg.io/9nw7kqrfb/Screen_Shot_2016_09_12_at_22_27_46.png)

but the data inside the boxes is not displaying in the same locations in each box if the image is too small.

if i make each box a set height, how can i make the product title and price display at the bottom of the box under each other so each both is exactly the same?

HTML for one box:

```
<li class="post-2483 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_brand-mikrotik product_cat-routers  instock featured taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
    <a href="#" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link"><span class="et_shop_image"><img width="300" height="180" src="#" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="mikrotik-rb2011" title="mikrotik-rb2011"><span class="et_overlay"></span></span><h3>Mikrotik RB2011 Advanced Wi-Fi Router</h3>
    <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>109.00</span> <small class="woocommerce-price-suffix">ex VAT</small></span>
</a></li>
```

Comment: Your html code would help us to help you !

Comment: apologies, see again

Comment: Have you considered trying `flex`? `display: flex;` on the parent `ul` and `flex: 1 1;` on the nested `li`s usually does the trick. http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: this code is used in wordpress so i cannot change the HTML easily but i can add custom CSS

Comment: @charlie You don't need to change the markup to try `flex`...

Comment: okay - what elements do i need to add this onto?

Comment: ok, just tried this and it works great but it messes with the number of products i have displaying which is set through wordpress/woocommerce - how can this be stopped so it only changes the size and positioning of the product boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using jquery to equalize the height of spans with **et_shop_image** class name.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var maxHeight=0;
  $(".et_shop_image").each(function(){
  if ($(this).height()>maxHeight){maxHeight=$(this).height()}
  });

  $(".et_shop_image").height(maxHeight);
})
```

Also make sure the class et_shop_image has `display:inline-block` or `block`

If you can not use javaScript and you are using HTML 5 , check the [flexbox](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). But you will need to revise the HTML codes too.